# Using external file with WP_USE_THEMES set to false causing 404

Tags: wordpress

I know there's a dedicated [WordPress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), however, I'm getting no traction over there.

I have a file in my WordPress template I want to use for a Twitter authentication callback named oauth.php that I'd like to be accessible through htp://mydomain.com/oauth.php:

```
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

echo "test";
```

However the file is throwing up a 404??

This actually a issue I'd like a solution for away from just this instance.

**EDIT**

Using the full file path works as intended, so:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/oauth.php
```

Is this bad practise?

Comment: I see there is an [open bug](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/764) for this. is it possible that your issue is related?

Comment: @MichaelDoye I don't think so Michael... I'm just looking to do some basic authentication within the file before redirecting back to the homepage. Just can't get the thing to work

Comment: using the full file path works @MichaelDoye so ``http://my-domain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/file.php``

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this in your **oauth.php**:

```
<?php
//Instead of setting to false, try comment it out
//define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Load the WordPress Environment */
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
// Fake a 200 OK status header
status_header(200);

//The rest of your code here
?>
```

This should allow you to access this file at `http://example.com/oauth.php` and run the code inside leveraging Wordpress functionality but without your template.

NOTE: This may depend on your wordpress version.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Still getting the 404, thanks though. Is it bad practise to use the absolute file path??